# application.yml config file in springboot

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, profiling, config

I had given application.yml like below

```
spring:
datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user
    username: root
    password: abc123
jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
```

But I am getting

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.

Help me to sort out this.

Comment: the driver: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" is deprecated, consider using this: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" . Also use driver-class-name

Answer (score 0):

change the name of your database, 'user' is a reserved keyword!!!